# Is to possible to translate any time signature to any time signature?

Tags: time-signatures, beats

Is to possible to translate any time signature to any time signature without even slight change in music?

Sometimes it is so hard to translate some time signatures to each other but finally is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably.  But it can get a bit silly.  All these bars sound the same, but you wouldn't want to continue this sort of notation for too long!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No! it's possible to sort of translate 2/2 into 4/4, but even then there will be a subtle change in emphasis of certain notes, depending where they are in a bar. It's certainly not possible to tranlate 3/4 into 6/8, even though they both contain the equivalent of 3 crotchets/6 quavers. 12/8 is often written as 4/4, with a note at the top explaining the feel, but that's hardly translation.

By doubling the value of every note, it's possible to change the bottom number in a time sig. from, say, 8 to 4, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you could translate one three time into another type of three time. So for instance...

[image: Example 1]

Into.

[image: Example 2]

You can also change the nature of a certain type of time. Or in other change a passage from Simple Time to Compound Time.

So for Instance take the next simple duple time passage and change it into a compound duple time.

[image: Example 3]

[image: Example 4]

Comment: Your last examples can't sound the same - there's a different number of dots.